# Bower info working even after removing the bower server

Tags: bower

I have installed private bower on one of my server and registered a component, which is fine. On one of my machine if i set the .bowerrc to point to this bower registry and then try bower info my-component. Its giving the valid version and all.

Now if I stopped the bower server and cleaned the bower cache on my client machine and try bower info its still showing the previous version infos instead of throwing the error not reachable or something.

How can i fix the issue?